# Does a ng-model work on ng-repeated fields?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am using ng-repeat and I am various levels in such as:

```
`ul in output.content.innercontent` or `li in ul.content.innercontent`
```

my input looks like this:

```
 <input id="{{input.key}}" name="{{input.label}}" type="text" 
        value="{{input.value}}" placeholder="{{input.defaultValue}}" 
       value="{{input.label}}" 
       class="form-control input-md" uib-tooltip="{{input.tooltip}}" 
       ng-if="input.type == 'input'">
```

On any one of those whenever a change happens and then an onBlur I want to make a call. Is this possible with ng-model & ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" with all these fields? The bind behavior I see online are mostly of an input to read-only field somewhere. Should I use ng-blur followed with a on("change") type of behavior?

Comment: you got two different value="" in the input and you forget the ng-model

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
 <input id="{{input.key}}" name="{{input.label}}" type="text" 
    ng-model="{{input.value}}"  <!-- this -->
   placeholder="{{input.defaultValue}}" 
   class="form-control input-md" uib-tooltip="{{input.tooltip}}" 
   ng-if="input.type == 'input'">
```

ng-model should do it

---

```
 <input ng-model-options"{updateOn: 'blur'}"/>
```

==> This update the model only when user get outside the input

---

To call a function on-blur :

```
 <input ng-blur="callThisFn()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit but ng-model-options"{updateOn: 'blur'}" updates where?

Comment: ng-model-options"{updateOn: 'blur'}"  update the variable you put on the ng-model only when you go outside of the input